# RabbitMQ undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rabbitmq

All of a sudden when I try to access RabbitMQ it only displays this on screen:

> undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Now it is showing browser default error:
`Connection Refused`

Comment: So is this Classic ASP or ASP.NET?  Have you tried looking to see if the requested file exists?

Comment: It is ASP .NET MVC, it is installed on command line linux and I am not good with command line. I haven't touched the server in a month so why would the file disappear?

Comment: Why would the file disappear?  Who knows, but that's the start for where you should be looking, based on the error message provided.

Comment: now it is showing default browser error: 
`connection` refused

Comment: Which RabbitMQ version ? are you using `guest` `guest` as credentials?

Comment: I am using v 3.3.5. I am not using any credentials as it does not load the login page. As soon as I go to the server. It either shows `Connection Refused` as default browser error or it shows `undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs`. When I check Firefox console it says `/js/tmpl/login.ejs?0.7230313879240866     1.99s` and `Error: 404 Not Found get `

I have just checked the directory on linux server and the login.ejs is available

Comment: Above the 404 Error, it shows this `runRoute get`

Another point which might help you understand the problem. On windows server's website log file shows: 

`server:5672 unavailable. Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was solved by restarting the Linux server as rabbitMQ commands were hanging and required force stop.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: had the same issue, node was down. deletd node from /var/lib/mnesia dir and started the rabbitmq worked for me

Comment: I was running RabbitMQ locally, restarting my Mac helped.

Comment: This did not work for me. Running RabbitMQ in Docker. Restarted my entire laptop. Error persists.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same symptoms on my Windows server running RabbitMQ after shutting down the RabbitMQ service, and it refused to start back up.

Steps I took to resolve the issue without a reboot:

1. The RabbitMQ log file named `rabbit@[SERVER_NAME_HERE].log` at folder `C:\Users\[ADMIN_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log` file was huge (12+ GB); I renamed it so that RabbitMQ could create a new log file.
2. I tried again to start the RabbitMQ service in services.msc, which failed (again).
3. The new `rabbit@[SERVER_NAME_HERE].log` file reported that a particular folder could not be deleted:

`cannot_delete,
                "c:/Users/[ADMIN_ACCOUNT_USERNAME_HERE]/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@[SERVER_NAME_HERE]-plugins-expand/rabbitmq_management-3.3.5/priv/www/cli",`

4. I tried to rename that `cli` folder in Windows Explorer and got a "That folder is in use by another process" error.
5. I downloaded the [Sysinternals Handle.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) utility and ran it with an argument of "RabbitMQ", which showed that the folder (`cli`) that the log file reported couldn't be deleted was being locked by a `rundll32.exe` process with a particular process ID.
6. I killed that `rundll32.exe` instance in Task Manager (after turning on display of Process IDs on the View menu).
7. I started the RabbitMQ service again, and this time, it worked!

**tl;dr**

A particular Windows process was locking a folder that RabbitMQ wanted to delete as a part of its startup process.  Identifying that process using the [Sysinternals Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) utility and then killing it allowed RabbitMQ to start up successfully.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using VPN (working from home) remember to check if the VPN connection is still active. It might just be that you need to reconnect to the network to reach the server.

Answer (score 4):

you can:

```
docker exec -it rabbitmq
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Answer (score 3):

The above comment from Emran helped me realise that I need to stop docker and rebuild the containers.

```
docker-compose stop
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, when I opened the route on an **incognito browser window**, it opened successfully.

Comment: okay, why does this work

Comment: removed some extension and the issue was resolved

Comment: Toss your cookies... same effect.

Answer (score 1):

if someone uses it in localhost I go to

> services.msc

and start the service

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue:

Error message:

> throw:{error,
>             {cannot_delete_plugins_expand_dir,
>                 ["/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand",
>                  {cannot_delete,
>                      "/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand/rabbitmq_amqp1_0-3.7.3/ebin/rabbitmq_amqp1_0.app",
>                      eacces}]}}

Manually deleted the files in bin and then restarted the rabbitmq server and it worked!

The reason was the previous rabbitmq service was shutdown incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, resulting from some problem in the rabbit MQ shutdown process. After uninstalling RabbitMQ and reinstalling (a newer version!) the problem still persisted. The problem was only resolved after I manually deleted the entire folder at `C:\Users\[ADMIN_ACCOUNT_USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ`