# RabbitMQ: There is no template at (...)

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I want to run RabbitMQ in a Docker container. So I found [this guide](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) which states that all you have to do is run this command:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```

And after that, RabbitMQ should be available in your browser on `http://container-ip:15672`. I'm not entirely sure what "container ip" is, but I assume it's `localhost` when running it on my own PC. But when I open that, I just get a blank page, with an error in the bottom:

> undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs undefined

[image: screenshot of error]

Now this seems to suggest that maybe there is something wrong with the image. But then I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338155/2445415) here on StackOverflow in which it is suggested to run the same image (as far as I can see) but with a different command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name mymq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

If I run this, it works just fine. Can anyone tell me why this is? To me it seems like I'm running the exact same image, just in a slightly different way?

**Update:**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935430/rabbitmq-undefined-there-is-no-template-at-js-tmpl-login-ejs) where someone had the same error. People seems to have solved it by changing configs or re-installing RabbitMQ. However, that doesn't explain why a newly started container exhibits this behaviour and only when started in a certain manner.

Comment: Most likely has something to do with the RabbitMQ Management Plugin.  This isn't even part of RabbitMQ core ( the core of RabbitMQ doesn't even have a web GUI ).

Comment: The latter command maps ports 5672 and 15672 in the container to the same ports on the host machine so they're accessible from outside the container. The instructions on the page you link that reference `container-ip` relies on a 'trick' that doesn't work on all host OSes. So the latter command, where you map the ports, is the right way to do it.

Comment: @HansKilian does that mean that if I don't state it explicitly, my PC doesn't know that `localhost:15672` should forward to the container running? That would make sense if it didn't work at all. But how does it cause the error I see - where it finds the container, but seems to be missing some files?

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen I couldn't reproduce the error you get when I tried. I just get 'connection refused'. And you're right. You shouldn't be able to access the container at all using localhost if the ports aren't mapped. Maybe your browser cached some of the content. Do you still get the template error if you refresh using ctrl+F5?

Comment: @HansKilian right, of course it was the cache (d'oh!). Thanks for the help.